# Unparseable output from pylint in emacs

Tags: 14.04, python, configuration, emacs, ide

I just upgraded from Ubuntu 12.04 to 14.04 (clean upgrade, not in-place).

I found that I couldn't call pylint from within emacs (M-x pylint) as I used to, so I installed the package python-mode.

Now I can call pylint from emacs, but even when I make it include line numbers (`pylint -f parseable foo.py`), emacs can't jump to the next error using next-error. When I try, I get the following error in the minibuffer:

"No buffers contain error message locations."

Any suggestions of what I can do to fix this would be much appreciated. Googling around only shows tips on how to get flymake to run pylint, which I'm not interested in doing.

For reference, here's a sample of what I see in the pylint output window in emacs:

> `No config file found, using default configuration
> /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pylint/reporters/text.py:79: UserWarning: parseable output format is deprecated. This is equivalent to --msg-template={path}:{line}: [{msg_id}({symbol}), {obj}] {msg}
>   'to --msg-template=%s' % (self.name, self.line_format))
> ************* Module video_demo
> video_demo.py:21: [E0602(undefined-variable), MatplotlibDisplay.__init__] Undefined variable 'figure'
> video_demo.py:25: [E0602(undefined-variable), MatplotlibDisplay.update] Undefined variable 'axes'
> video_demo.py:28: [E0602(undefined-variable), MatplotlibDisplay.update] Undefined variable 'figure'
> video_demo.py:35: [E0213(no-self-argument), VideoDisplay.update] Method should have "self" as first argument
> video_demo.py:50: [E1103(maybe-no-member),`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fixed it, by doing this:

Step one: uninstall the python-mode Ubuntu package. It was doing more harm than good, especially with the tabbing behavior.

Step two: add this line to my .emacs file:

`(require 'tramp)`

This got rid of the error, when calling `M-x pylint`, of the`tramp-tramp-p` function being missing. Apparently this is a bug in Ubuntu 14.04's copy of pylint.el, that has since been patched upstream (see [this pull request](https://bitbucket.org/logilab/pylint/pull-request/141/pylintel-missing-dependency-on-tramp/diff#chg-elisp/pylint.el)).